# How to fix the error validation check account?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i made the login, the rules if the login true, the login will enter to next form, if another one input true show nottification "username and password not valid, and if all input false back to form login. the error said in form 31 but i think the syntax are correct, what's wrong about the syntax ?

this is codeigniter 3.10 and PHP 7, line 31 in syntax $num_account = count($temp_account);

this is the controller

```
 public function login()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username','true');
        $password = $this->input->post('password','true');

        $temp_account = $this->user_model->check_user_account($username,$password)->row();
        //check account
        $num_account = count($temp_account);

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('account/form_login');
        }
        else {
            if ($num_account > 0) {
                //kalau ada set session
                $array_items = array(
                    'id_user' => $temp_account->id_user,
                    'username' => $temp_account->username,
                    'logged_in' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($array_items);
                redirect(site_url('account/view_success_page'));
            } else {
                //kalau ga ada diredirect lagi ke halaman login
                $this->session->set_flashdata('notification', 'Peringatan : Username dan Password tidak cocok');
                redirect(site_url('account'));
            }
        }
    }
```

> Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
>   Filename: controllers/account.php
>   Line Number: 31

**Method:**

```
function check_user_account($username,$password) { 
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('user'); 
    $this->db->where('username',$username); 
    $this->db->where('password',$password); 
    return $this->db->get(); 
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  You should `var_dump($temp_account);` to see what it contains.

Comment: `check_user_account` can you please show your code of this method

Comment: function check_user_account($username,$password)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        return $this->db->get();
    }

Comment: then why are you using `->row()` remove this part, it will give you proper array

Comment: because i  the exemple using ->row(), when I delete the row() if i
Incorrect the input data still entered to next form

Comment: i think u need to move your query in ELSE part, otherwise your query will be executed with empty user and password

Comment: Is your `password` stored in plain text on your database?

Comment: also try with `count((array)$temp_account);`

Comment: second, i dont know why are you using count here, if your query is running, you will only get 1 record, why not num_rows checking here?

Comment: glad to help u ...